# Google Slides API: Increase Page Size in Create Presentation

Tags: java, google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

How do I increase the size of a page in Google Slides? Right now the page size is confined to Widescreen 16:9. The following is not working in Java, is this a bug perhaps with Google Slides API? It doesn't seem to recognize Page Size Properties

```
String titleSlide = "SlideTest";
Dimension ptHeight = new Dimension().setMagnitude(12000.0).setUnit("PT");
Dimension ptWidth= new Dimension().setMagnitude(12000.0).setUnit("PT");

Presentation presentation = new Presentation()
                                .setPageSize(new Size()
                                    .setHeight(ptHeight)
                                    .setWidth(ptWidth))
                                .setTitle(titleSlide);

presentation = service.presentations()
        .create(presentation)
        .setFields("presentationId")
        .execute();
```

[Google Slides Page Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQBAt.png)

**Resources:**

[Google Slide API CreateSlideRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#createsliderequest)

[Google Slide API PageElementProperties](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#pageelementproperties)

Comment: In your tags, `google-apps-script` is included. Can I ask you about the reason of this? For example, do you want to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script?

Comment: well sometimes people familiar with google-apps-script can help, it definitely doesn't work in Java while testing cc @Tanaike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the `pageSize` not affecting the size of the pages in the presentation. This was reported in Google's Issue Tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119321089

Add a "star" next to the issue number to indicate you are affected by it.

Comment: hi, do you possibly know the answer for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66795794/google-slides-api-able-to-use-hexadecimal-to-set-colors thanks