# Google Slides API, able to use Hexadecimal to set Colors?

Tags: google-slides-api, google-slides

Is it possible to set Element Shape background color with Hexadecimal format eg  #B6D7A8 ? I see an example here,
[Google Slides API- How to change text color for all shapes of a certain color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64252844/google-slides-api-how-to-change-text-color-for-all-shapes-of-a-certain-color)

However, the Google Slide API reference does not mention it. I want to be sure, and specifically for Java environment.

https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#Page.OpaqueColor

```
    requests.add(new Request()
            .setUpdateShapeProperties(new UpdateShapePropertiesRequest()
                .setObjectId(elementRandomString)
                    .setShapeProperties(new ShapeProperties()
                            .setShapeBackgroundFill(new ShapeBackgroundFill()
                                .setSolidFill(new SolidFill()
                                        .setColor(new Col)
```

[image]

Comment: if there is community interested in doing this, can someone open up a Google Issues tracker here? I feel reluctant to do so, since I've already opened up 2 in last week, if there is community interest feel free to do so,  thanks https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues?q=componentid:191598%20status:open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided in the post [Google Slides API- How to change text color for all shapes of a certain color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64252844/google-slides-api-how-to-change-text-color-for-all-shapes-of-a-certain-color) uses [Slide Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides) in Apps Script to set the color.

To answer your question, it is not possible to set the color in HEX format.
As mentioned in the reference document that you provided, You need to provide an [RgbColor](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#rgbcolor) object in your [OpaqueColor](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#opaquecolor).

### Workaround:

1. Convert your hex color to `RGB` then divide `red`, `blue` and `green` value by `255` to obtain the [RgbColor](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#rgbcolor) accepted value which is `0.0 ~ 1.0`

You might want to consider this as reference: java : [convert Hex color #RRGGBB to rgb r g b?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227036/java-convert-hex-color-rrggbb-to-rgb-r-g-b)

2. Set [RgbColor](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#rgbcolor) based on your converted `red`, `blue` and `green` value.

### Sample Code:

```
requests.add(new Request()
            .setUpdateShapeProperties(new UpdateShapePropertiesRequest()
                .setObjectId(elementRandomString)
                    .setShapeProperties(new ShapeProperties()
                            .setShapeBackgroundFill(new ShapeBackgroundFill()
                                .setSolidFill(new SolidFill()
                                        .setColor(new Color()
                                                .setRgbColor(new RgbColor()
                                                      .setRed(redFloatValue)
                                                      .setBlue(blueFloatValue)
                                                      .setGreen(greenFloatValue))))))));
```

### **References:**

- [Google Slides API Javadoc documentation - Class OpaqueColor](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-slides/latest/com/google/api/services/slides/v1/model/OpaqueColor.html)
- [Google Slides API Javadoc documentation - Class RgbColor](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-slides/latest/com/google/api/services/slides/v1/model/RgbColor.html)

Comment: By the way, I was not able to reproduce your concern due to lack of environment platform. Please let me know if there is an issue with the sample code provided Thanks

Comment: ok, thanks, I am familiar with RGB as mentioned in question resource, I will just use that then, by the way,  can you have someone update this feature request? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66715704/google-slides-api-increase-page-size-in-create-presentation    its been reported as a bug, people are aware of stack, maybe they forgot about it, I am not sure,  thanks https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119321089

Comment: I'm sorry about that but I don't have enough permissions to seek for an update regarding the issues/features submitted

Comment: hi, just placed another question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66863716/google-slides-rotate-rectangle-35-degrees

Comment: Hi I'm sorry, due to our guidelines changes it is not possible for me to support cases created outside my shift. Rest assured your posted question can be supported by someone within our team